# Is there a way to run one query across multiple tables in a database in MYSQL repeatedly?

Tags: mysql, sql, list, loops, csv

I want to save  csv file of all the tables in my MYSQL database, doing this one by one would be hectic.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dynamic_pro()
BEGIN
DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 40;

set @table_arr=  concat((SELECT group_concat(distinct table_name)   FROM information_schema.columns where table_schema='case2'));


  WHILE v1 > 0 DO
    
    SET @s = CONCAT('?statement?');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    SET v1 = v1 - 1;
  END WHILE;
END
//
delimiter ;

execute dynamic_pro;
```

The `@table_arr` give the list of tables in the schema.

I want to run the query inside `concat()` so that it iterates through the `@table_arr` to run the query for each table in MYSQL Workbench

Comment: Can you not use EXPORT in phpMyAdmin

Comment: Or the command line